# Sign in with Linkedin OAuth 2.0 using http GET request (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, linkedin-api

After Linkedin's javascript SDK deprecation, my site's "Sign in with Linkedin" method stopped working, and now I have to update it to use the new OAuth 2.0 authentication process.

In my single page application webapp (Angular 5), I used to make a http GET request from my front-end code, subscribe (rxjs) to it and ask user for authorization in a popup window. After permission was granted, popup closed automatically and I was able to get a response in my subscription. This allowed a good user experience, because no redirects were needed, and I was able to get the next action without leaving the original page.

After OAuth 2.0 became mandatory, I just can't figure out how to build this same behavior, as a redirect URI is required in https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization, and if I try to make a http GET request to this same uri I face a CORS policy error saying "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue using Linkedin's new OAuth 2.0 API??

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
authorizeLinkedin (): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .get(
      `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social`)
    .pipe(catchError((error: any) => this.errorHandler(error)))
  }

signinWithLinkedin (): void {
    this.socialAuth.getLinkedinAuth().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please, share the code you've been trying so far.

Comment: I've updated my question with a code sample, it's pretty simples actually.

Comment: did you find anything ?

Comment: No =/. Share the solution if you find it =)

Comment: hi @FelipeMicali getting same error. share the solution if you find it ? Please need a help. Any help really appriciated